# Application of Chain Rule in Hirsch's text

Tags: dynamical-systems

In the attachment is one page that I extract from the book "Differential Equations, Dynamical Systems, and an Introduction to Chaos".  The two equations are highlighted.

I think the second one is incorrect, and I insert a question right below it.  I inspect two different editions of the book and it is the same. It seems to be just a simple chain rule, and this drives me crazy.

Could you help explain why the second highlighted equation is written as it is?

Thanks much!

Comment: There is not link attached!

Comment: Better yet, typeset the equations using MathJax.